# SORL thumbnail converts to blank - Django

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

Iv always been using SORL to create thumbnails.
This time it creates the thumbnails but they are all just blank images. I even tried easy_thumbnails but it does not even return a thumbnail src for the image.

The thumbnail images are all there in the _thumbs dir but all with ZERO kb size.

I dont have a clue why this is happening

Comment: I suspect its not sorl or easy_thumnails that is the problem. Probably PIL or something?

Comment: is this the same server, project, and app that was previously working? Or are you creating a new project similar to what you've done in the past?